# How can search in SO with user + tag information?

Tags: support, search

Let's say I need to search in SO with tag 'sqlite' and user 'prosseek'.

How can I do that in search panel?

I tried 'user:prosseek [tag] sqlite', but I got nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close.  Since user names aren't unique, you cannot search that way.

Do it like so:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:260127+[sqlite]
```

Or, if you are the currently logged user, you can do:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+[sqlite]
```

Comment: Thanks, the first answer works fine with me!