# User search should allow filtering by tag to make large results manageable

Tags: feature-request, user-search

I'm looking for a particular tidbit of information and I can't seem to find it via regular search or Google, but I remember it was in an answer by a particular user "Matt". I would probably recognize his gravatar, too, but I have absolutely no clue [what his user number is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65185/how-can-search-in-so-with-user-tag-information). So I try the [user search page](https://stackoverflow.com/users).

There are 124 pages of users on SO whose handle is "Matt"! It seems the only way to find this person is by clicking through those pages, one by one, looking for the gravatar. I know that he's got a lot of posts in particular tags, though. What if I could pare down this enormous list?

Trying to dig up an answer based on who posted it is just one use case, but the point is that looking for a particular user is nearly impossible for common handles (like real-life given names).

Adding the ability to filter the result of a user name search by a tag or tags the user has posts in would make it a lot easier.

Comment: Well until this gets implemented you can always use this [data.se query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65448/looking-for-posts-by-a-user-and-tag?TagName=objective-c&UserName=Matt)

Comment: Thanks Conrad. It was a contrived situation this time, but I certainly appreciate it. Clever figuring out which tag I would be searching, though!